# How to send email with php without the mail landing automaticly in the trash box

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, recycle-bin

Im using PHP's mail() function to send some emails. But all my mails land automaticly in the trash box. Is there a way of preventing this? If so, where should i read to learn more about it.

Would you recommend me using PHPmailer?

Best of regards,
Alexander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you mean thrash box at the receiver's end. So basically the receiving email server is regarding it as spam.  This can happen if:

1) The IP you are sending from is already blacklisted for spamming (happens often in shared hosting)

2) The IP and domain are relatively new and unknown.

(Note that many times, newsletters from well established sites also end up in spam).

If its your dedicated IP, then setting RDNS for the IP, to match the domain name will very likely solve the issue. Another usual practice is to alert the receiver (if she is subscribing on your website) to check their thrash/spam folder and whitelist your email address in their mail account.

regards,

JP

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR: There's no magic bullet. Just because you can learn how to form an email in PHP, does not guarantee it is routed to someone's mailbox, or even accepted. Success is based on reputation, not any single fix.

I am (edit: was) a mail server engineer, have written SpamAssassin rules, and have deep-dived issues for customers sending or receiving email.

The recipient's mail server scans your email, looking for attributes and "historical problems" (lack of mail agent, coming from your webserver IP, etc). These get "points". The total number of points is compared, and the recipient's server may do one or more of the following:

- List item
- refused during SMTP,
- routed to Spam folder,
- routed to Inbox, but tagged "***SPAM***"
- blackholed (accepted, then mysteriously lost).

"Points" (score) only means something to a particular anti-spam solution. There is no public test. Fix ALL the problems you can, and success goes up.

*The #1 issue is: do not send email directly to the recipient's SMTP server. This network space sends 99.9% spam. It costs money to scan email, so a good email admin will block or refuse such connections.

The "fix" for your source IP is: Use an SMTP Gateway. The gateway can be our ISP mailserver, or a commercial service. Check first with their terms of service. They may prohibit sending emails using an authenticated web form, since these are so frequently abused ("someone hacked me" is not an excuse).

If you have email hosting, do the following: create a mailbox called for example 'website-notification@websitedomain.com'. Call it what you like.  Now you want your PHP script to send the email -through- that address, using **Authenticated SMTP**. *I'll leave the process of learning how to use Authenticated SMTP from PHP as a learning exercise for you -- there are many tutorials online).*

Once you send emails *through* your valid SMTP server, the mail is seen as "originating" from your SMTP gateway. It's not seen as coming from your script. But this isn't the end of the story

2. As someone else noted, Be sure you are not missing display headers such as To: From: Subject: and Date:. Strictly speaking these headers are NOT "required" in email handshaking, but in practical terms no reputable email software omits them. Also, Date must be in the standard date format, or some spam filters will flag it.

This topic is not to be confused with "envelope headers" (the hidden stuff in the SMTP handshaking), which *also* can also impact your score. Using an SMTP Gateway usually takes care of this (since the recipient's mailserver will handshake with your gateway host).

3. Your FROM address must be VALID. Do not use a fake domain. Do not use your domain name with a fake mailbox name. Some anti-spam software will do a "Sender Verify" to test if the From address is bogus or fake (oversimplified: they'll try sending a reply and see if you would accept it or not).

The #1 mistake is setting your from address as "noreply@yourdomain.com", and not creating that mailbox. When that happens, everyone's "Sender Verify" on your email fails, and you look like a spammer covering their tracks.

4. If your domain DNS has an SPF record, be 100% sure it lists every IP that might send email for your domain. This is a technical topic. Having a valid, correct SPF record helps your deliverability a little bit. But if you misunderstand and create a bad (incorrect) SPF record, you will be worse off. Take your time to understand before using this.
5. If you have a business with a real address or PO box, don't use "Domain Registration Privacy" or "Domain Proxy" services if you can avoid it. When this was written (2011) It used to be very true that anonymizing services could get your mail blocked, or "tagged spam". This is less true today, but it's still worth considering.
6. Know the IP address of your mailserver, and regularly check that it is not "blacklisted" at SpamCop, SpamHaus, or the Barracuda spam blacklists. Google for more. There are monitoring services, and scripts which can alert you. But if you get on these lists, it means there is something else happening you were not monitoring for...

As said, no simple answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

JP's answer is partly correct but it also could be your header's in the email i know from experience this sends stuff to the spam folder try the following;

set the emails to your domain something like no-reply or a valid reply.

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: very true.. should try this fix first.

Answer (score 0):

This probably has something to do with your mail client and spam settings configuration. Try opening account on `gmail.com` and sending email there, if it's OK you know it is your mail server/client problem. If it's not, post your PHP code and full email headers of the email you've got.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because many a times, headers are missing / if its a well known email server domain key signature is not present, or something like that. If you already have a separate email server, you should check out if you can use the PHP Pear Mail package to send email using your email server, rather than directly via mail function. That's what I find convenient, as its much more flexible.